# Composite key in sqoop --hbase-row-key

Tags: hbase, sqoop

Is there a way where we can set composite key in --hbase-row-key in sqoop command.
Something like: `--hbase-row-key column1,column2`

Also, can we somehow start the key in hbase from 1 and sort of auto-increment it for each new row entry from mysql. When another sqoop process runs, we can pick up the last max id, and increment it from there itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately Sqoop currently do not support either of your requests. You can specify only one column to be used as HBase's row key. I would recommend you to create a new ticket on [Sqoop's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP) to ask for such functionality.

**Edit:**

Ability to import into HBase using multiple columns as a row key has been added via SQOOP-1038 in Sqoop 1.4.4.